# include virtual does not work inside if block in classic asp but works outside

Tags: asp-classic, include

For some reason if my include is inside if statement, it does work. I get

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

but I include the same line outside if, it renders correct and displays the form. Am I missing anything?

```
<% elseif EmailError <> "?" then %>
                <p class="StdParaHead">Can't Send Message</p>
                <p style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Please fill in
                <%if EmailError="NameBlank" then
                    Response.Write "your name"
                ElseIf EmailError = "EmailBlank" OR EmailError = "InvalidEmail" then
                    Response.Write "a valid e-mail address"
                ElseIf EmailError = "LocationBlank" then
                    Response.Write "your City and State"
                ElseIf EmailError = "BadSecurity" then
                    Response.Write "the proper security information"
                End if
                %></p>
                <p>clause1 </p>
<!--#include virtual="/includes/Content/ContactFormNew.inc"--> /* does not work here */

    <% else %>
                <p class="StdParaHead">Sorry...</p>
                <p>Due to an uncertain error, your message could not be sent at this time. Please see our <a href="contact.asp">contact information</a> for other ways to contact Axiom Valuation Solutions, or try again later.</p>
                <p><a href="/newlook/newsite/default.asp">Home</a></p>
                <p> CLAUSE 2</p>
<!--#include virtual="/includes/Content/ContactFormNew.inc"--> /* does not work */
    <%end if%>
<!--#include virtual="/includes/Content/ContactFormNew.inc"--> /* works here */
```

Comment: the http status code 500 stands for an error in a server side script. but there must be a detailed description of that error. either check your iis logs or change iis to send script errors to browser to get a detailed error description. furthermore if you are viewing the page in ie set the checkbox "display detailed http errors" in preferences.

Comment: Can you paste the code from `/includes/Content/ContactFormNew.inc`?

Comment: Please note that conditional includes are not possible in ASP Classic. Your script **will include the file anyway**. Based on the if-else structure, certain includes will be processed.

Comment: Well I have not gotten detailed error. The problem is this. I verified this by removing and putting back in. ContactFormNew.inc is just an asp file which has some javascript too. It works fine as of last include in the code. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Uhm, we cannot help you if you do not post relevant code from `ContactFormNew.inc`. Something in that file is messing things up.

Comment: BTW I have looked at other QA and found that you *can* include file conditionally in classic asp. That part should work. So far I am living with it as it is and the client is OK with it. I personally would like to know why could this be a problem. Sorry wont be able to post the reference file, it contains quite a bit of code. But I can experiment with a test reference file and I will be able to post that if the problem still exists.

Comment: why do you want to include the file inside the if / else? you include it on both blocks either so you could easily include it outside only once?

Comment: @GuidoGautier, your comments was correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my best guess is that you define some variables in your "ContactFormNew.inc".

as you cannot "dynamically" include files like you are trying to do the file is included twice.

that is because the include is done BEFORE any ASP code is interpreted and the content of "ContactFormNew.inc" is injected two times (in elseif end else block).

so the file is included twice and then the error is obviuos you defined the same variable twice...

Comment: I will give it a try but the error that I get is "file not found" inside if block. Outside, it works without any problem.

Comment: Also @Guido comment in the OP addressed this right. I included the file once and everything was fine :) Bottom, line, include the same file in if-else, both will be included. But the error here is very strange and totally misleading, `file not found`